# How to calculate a value based on a column of a previous row in a GROUP BY using SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

For example if have the following table:

```
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
fk_driver_id INTEGER -- ignore this for now
lap INTEGER
lap_time INTEGER -- date stored as epoch
```

How can I based on this data calculate the exact time driven for each lap. I want to do a GROUP BY `lap` and then calculate the exact round time by suptracting the previous round time from the 'current' round time.

Note: the `lap_time` is the total time driven when crossing the finish.

**Example data** (simplified the lap_time to just seconds(:

```
id     fk_driver_id     lap     lap_time     
1      1                1       65
2      1                2       123
3      1                3       183
4      1                4       250
5      1                5       311
6      1                6       373
7      1                7       430
```

**Desired results:**

```
fk_driver_id     lap     lap_time
1                1       65
1                2       58
1                3       60
1                4       67
1                5       61
1                6       65
1                7       62
```

Comment: Could you post some example data (expected result, etc.)? I guess also that there will be many different lap times for each lap (because we can have many drivers). How do you manage it?

Comment: You have no column called `round_time`.  You have a very conveniently named column called `lap_time`, which seems to be what you want.

Comment: @AlexZen thank you for your response/. I've added some example data, please take a look. The filtering for the drivers is irrelevant, for now the lap_time is the main issue.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The round_time should be a calculated field based on the difference between lap times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to relate different records of the same table, you must join the table to itself and give the 2 instances different aliases

```
SELECT
    b.fk_driver_id,
    b.lap,
    b.lap_time - IFNULL(a.lap_time, 0) AS time_per_lap
FROM
    MyTable b
    LEFT JOIN MyTable a
        ON b.lap - 1 = a.lap AND b.fk_driver_id = a.fk_driver_id
ORDER BY
    b.fk_driver_id, b.lap
```

See: [SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/8753b/10/0)

We must make an outer join for the case that there is no previous lap to compare with (for the first lap) .

And since there is only one `lap_time` per driver and lap, I guess, there is nothing to GROUP BY, unless you want to calculate an average lap time.

Comment: I'll try it first thing tomorrow! Thanks for your quick response, I think this will do the trick. I'll let you know tomorrow.